# Most Common Parses of the English language?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I hope I've got the right forum. I want to know about English specifically, although this is a linguistics question.

A common task in NLP and Computational Linguistics is to generate parse trees for various sentences.  How these sentences are parsed, for one, depends upon POS tagging which itself depends upon how to enumerate the Part of Speeches of the language.

What I am interested in is sort of a reverse view of the process.  Just as I can ask what are the most common words for the English Language, I wish to ask what are the most common parses for the English Language which are found, if in fact this can be measured or approximated?  I am interested in the fully expanded representations, not something as basic as `NP VP`.  For example: one might render:

`The bat eats a cat`

```
d    n   v   d  n
```

using one simplistic POS enumeration.  Looking at this parse, I would ask what percentage of sentences in English follow this exact pattern?

Comment: I've flagged this non-prejudicially as being better suited to the Linguistics site.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. As [Abney (1995)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/abney95c.pdf) demonstrates, far more sentences in English **can** be parsed in any particular way than ever **would** be parsed that way by a human.

Comment: @StoneyB That makes sense, but sometimes when you say a specific language, they frown on your question.

Comment: maybe you should be asking that at the computational linguistics Q&A http://linguistics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: That's more general linguistics, though also some computational linguists hang out there, too. There ought to be a S.E for computational linguistics, though I suspect they've already got something equivalent of their own going.

Comment: @JohnLawler "corpora" mailing list (http://www.hit.uib.no/corpora/) is a bit like that

Comment: @demongolem just out of curiosity, of what practical use would the top-N POS-tag sequences be?

Comment: @Mikhail Given a POS-tag sequence and a vocabulary which is a very small subset of the English language, come up with a valid English sentence.  Or perhaps better, given said vocabulary and a couple of related POS-tag sequences, try to do the same thing for any one sequence.

Comment: @demongolem does "Beer flies brown umbrella" count as a valid sentence?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of parsings, each with a percentage? Like
_(Art N) (ModV to V (Art Adj N))_    5%
_(Art N) (V (Art N (RelPron VP))_    4.5%
...
?

Comment: A list would be interesting here but is usually considered not constructive. Maybe just references would be best?

Comment: @Mikhail Likely not, but it depends upon the vocab I am working with.  I think I am going to do some light anaylsis as a strart myself like maybe take 100 news articles, extract sentences and run it through the Stanford POS tool, but I don't have the time or resources currently to develop my own extensive corpus so I was hoping there would be some numbers somewhere.

Comment: @demongolem my point was that this sentence would have exactly the same POS sequence (N V Adj N) as a bunch of valid sentences, such as "Cat likes red fish". I.e. POS sequence is not enough to generate a valid sentence and neither is syntax. If I were you, I would either check the grammars available (like http://www.delph-in.net/erg/), or generate the possible candidates using POS sequences or syntax trees and then select those that get the top rank from a language model. The latter has a problem, though, since many language models don't care about sentence beginning/end.

Comment: I am going to try running some of the [BYU Corpora](http://corpus.byu.edu/)  through [MorphAdorner](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/documentation/nupos/), then analyze the results.

Comment: Also note that you can make POS queries for BYU corpora on their site *but* unless you're looking for a specific construction there will probably be too many occurrences and no results will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

I would utilize projects like

- http://books.google.com/ngrams/info/
- http://nltk.org
- google-ngram-stripper

plus some programming skills to get such statistics.